# Select <li> elements from div/ul

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, crm

I am learning selenium/C#/Nunit trying to write test for selecting li.
[element]

[image]

Here is my code of lines:

```
dropdown= driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[@class='listview listview-scroll']/ul/li[@id='ext-gen1043']"));
dropdown.Click();
```

I have been getting `Selenium.NoSuchElementException`  nessage.

I did try with `Thread.Sleep(10000);` as well but I am unable to resolve this issue.

Comment: There is no li element with `ext-gen1043` id on the screenshot. You can right click the element in DevTools and copy its xpath, it might help you constructing your own properly. Also, those might be generated, judging from the naming.

Comment: Thanks T.s for you comment. you are correct. I am learning , Baby steps:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `css` selector:

```
dropdown= driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li[data-item-marker=Defense]"));  // the same way find all other li you need
```

`ext-gen1043` is dynamically generated. Do not use such locators ever. Even on your screenshot locator was changed.

Also, get rid of `Thread.Sleep(10000)` as soon as you will understand how to use implicit/explicit waits. This is bad practice to use `Sleep`.

Comment: You saved me. Thank you so much for your guidance I will definitely learn about Implicit/explicit wait.